# Entity Framework SaveChanges() not reflecting on entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, entity-framework-6

I have a Winforms project and a database running on SQL Server which has 2 tables, `Student` and `Standard`.

First I created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model from the database with the wizard help thing. Then I have a `DataGridView` control which has a bindingsource as DataSource.

NOTE: `DataBindingProjection` is a class that I created to be able to populate `DataGridView` with properties from both `Student` and `Standard` entities

I have this code:

```
var query = context.Students
                  .Include(s => s.Standard)
                  .Select(s => new DataBindingProjection
                  {
                      StudentID = s.StudentID,
                      StudentName = s.StudentName,
                      DateOfBirth = s.DateOfBirth,
                      Height = s.Height,
                      Weight = s.Weight,
                      StandardName = s.Standard.StandardName,
                      Standard_StandardId = s.Standard.StandardId
                  }).ToList();

            myList = new BindingList<DataBindingProjection>(query.ToList());
            dataBindingProjectionBindingSource.DataSource = myList;
            dataBindingProjectionDataGridView.DataSource = dataBindingProjectionBindingSource;
```

the grid is populated however, when I call `context.SaveChanges()`, it doesn't update the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Select` method on `DbSet` to project data to non-entity class will destroy the link to the original data. In your case, you should bind to `Student` class directly.

To bind to properties in `Standard` class, you can extends `Student` by adding property to it because it is a partial class.

```
partial class Student {
    public StandardName { 
       get { return this.Standard.StandardName; }
       set { this.Standard.StandardName = value; }
    }
}
```

Assuming that `Standard` property will never be null.

Comment: I need to access a property that belongs to the Standard entity, how would I do this?

Comment: Setup a relationship between Student and Standard, then you will be able to access the other via a property.  It's best if you let EF handle that for you.